# How can i get the correct url for style background url when i use the html-loader?

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, webpack-html-loader

for example, if i have a `test.html` file, the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/test.css">
  <style>
    .test {
      background: url("/images/banner.jpg");
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="/images/banner.jpg" alt="test"/>
</body>
</html>
```

i use `html-loader` to require it, just like:

```
const html = require(test.html);
console.log(html);
```

and the variable `html` print:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="[object Object]">
  <style>
    .test {
      background: url("/images/banner.jpg");
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="/temp/images/banner.d0f7ff.jpg" alt="test"/>
</body>
</html>
```

the `style` -> `.test` -> `background` can't get the correct url. How to resolve it ?

This is my `webpack` config code about `html-loader`:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  include: [
    path.resolve(config.devDir)
  ],
  loader: 'html',
  query: {
    root: config.devDir,
    attrs: ['img:src', 'img:data-src', 'link:href']
  }
}
```

Comment: pass it thru url-loader before html-loader, `loader:html!url`

Comment: I have fine the [interpolation option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader#interpolation) to solve this problem